# How to compute different metric values in cross validation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I am using scikit-lear for classification. I am using cross validation for finding effectiveness of the classification algorithm. I want to compute accuracy, precision, recall, F1 measure. Currently I am using following code.

```
           dt  =  DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=dt_est)
           dt_acc = cross_validation.cross_val_score(dt,x_data_tfidf.toarray(), target_arr, cv=cv,                  scoring='accuracy')
           dt_f1 = cross_validation.cross_val_score(dt,x_data_tfidf.toarray(), target_arr, cv=cv,scoring='f1')
           dt_pre = cross_validation.cross_val_score(dt,x_data_tfidf.toarray(), target_arr, cv=cv, scoring='precision')     
           dt_re = cross_validation.cross_val_score(dt,x_data_tfidf.toarray(), target_arr, cv=cv, scoring='recall')
```

Is there any way using which I can get all (accuracy, precision, recall, f1) in single computation? Currently I have to compute all the metric individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible out of the box, but we are working on it.
You can [define your own scoring object](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/model_evaluation.html#implementing-your-own-scoring-object) that computes all of them and prints them / stores them somewhere.

FYI an unfinished PR is [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/2759).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is any wrapper function is provided by sklearn but something like this
can save you some time.

scores = ['accuracy', 'f1', 'precision', 'recall']

metrics = {score: cross_validation.cross_val_score(dt,x_data_tfidf.toarray(), target_arr, cv=cv,scoring=score) for score in scores}